# Integrate an html template to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a basic html template using HTML5 and CSS. I want to integrate it to wordpress. How do i do that? I am new to wordpress. And also can I integrate a template created with angular material?

Comment: You can take a course from [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/bootstrap-to-wordpress) or u can try this one [Musexpress](http://www.musexpress.net) but i don't recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link..

(https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)